# iOS Refresh Accessibility Label

Tags: ios, objective-c, accessibility, voiceover

I have a button with accessibility label `@"a"`. When the button is pressed, I have a callback that sets the accessibility label `button.accessibilityLabel = @"b"`. I know this line of code runs. However, if I tap the button again, VoiceOver still reads a. Unfortunately, the code I'm working with is proprietary, so I can't share it directly.

However, in general, I would like to know what issues might cause VoiceOver to not recognize an update to a label.

Comment: Your question is not clear, try posting your code & what you tried

Comment: Your question is not clear

Comment: Any unclarity in what is being asked is due to ignorance of the reader. This is a fine question, with a valuable answer.

Answer (score 3):

THE BEST way to handle dynamic accessibility labels is to override the property functions on the views that are being focused (EX: on a UIButton). This allows TWO things. A: it's a lot easier to maintain than setting the property everywhere it can change. B: you can log information and see when the system is requesting that information, so you can better understand WHY things are happening. So even if it doesn't directly fix your issue, seeing WHEN the system requests your value, and logging that data, is inherently valuable.

> Doing this in Objective C

```
@implementation YourUIButton

-(NSString*)accessibilityLabel {
    if(someCondition) {
        return @"a";
    } else {
        return @"b";
    }
}

@end
```

> In Swift

```
public class YourUIButton : UIButton
    override public var accessibilityLabel: String? {
        get {
            if (someCondition) {
                return "a"
            } else {
                return "b"
            }
        }

        set {
            NSException.raise(NSException("AccessibilityLabelException", "You should not set this accessibility label.", blah))
        }
    }
}
```

You could also use this logic JUST to debug, and allow setting and such.

There are a lot of potential issues here. Race conditions, which view is actually getting focus, is there some parent child relationship going on, etc. Overriding the property and adding logging statements to the above code will help you understand what view is actually getting the accessibility label requested and when. Super valuable information!

Answer (score 3):

Use this while changing button text

```
UIAccessibility.post(notification: .layoutChanged, argument: yourButton)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to add `UIAccessibilityTraitUpdatesFrequently` to your buttons property `accessibilityTraits`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    myButton.accessibilityTraits |= UIAccessibilityTraitUpdatesFrequently
}
```

Also, when changing `accessibilityLabel` be sure that you're on main thread.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    myButton.accessibilityLabel = @"b";
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I actually wasn't calling from the main thread. However, when I use the dispatch_async block as you suggested, VoiceOver still reads the old label. Any other ideas?

Comment: @kmell96, VoiceOver reads the label instantly after the tap (as you can see using Calculator app), try to set `accessibilityLabel` to `nil` right after a tap and in callback set it to `@"b"`

Comment: The reference to UIAccessibilityTraitUpdatesFrequently is misleading as to that traits purpose. The rest of this post is reasonable.

Answer (score -2):

You don't really need a way to *refresh* the voice over labels. Its done automatically. I have tried this and it works as expected.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var tapCount = 0

    var button: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setTitle("Hello", for: .normal)
        button.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 100, height: 50)
        view.addSubview(button)

        button.accessibilityLabel = "Hello Button"
        button.accessibilityHint = "Tap here to start the action"
        button.accessibilityIdentifier = "hello_button"
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTap(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    @IBAction func buttonTap(sender:UIButton) {
        tapCount = tapCount + 1
        sender.accessibilityLabel = "Hello button, tapped \(tapCount) times"
    }
}
```

What Voice oversays:

**Hello Button**-pause-**Button**-pause-**Tap here to start the action**

On button tap

**Hello button, tapped one times**

Another tap

**Hello button, tapped two times**

Comment: Topicstarter does the same, but VoiceOver don't catch an edit

Comment: Downvoters I need you valuable comments to improve this.

Comment: @GRiMe2D, how do you know topicstarter had done the same? I have pasted a simple snippet how this works, so this the OP does not miss anything essential. If the OP's case is different , we can alywas update the question as well as answer.